# Valgrind reports memory leak with asprintf

Tags: c, linux, valgrind

Here is a piece of code that writes an HTTP response on a socket based on a simple struct

```
void write_response(request *req, response *resp, int socket) {
  char *raw_resp;
  int bytes = 0;

  asprintf(&raw_resp, "HTTP/1.1 %d %s\r\n", resp->code, resp->reason_phrase);

  bytes += strlen(raw_resp);
  for (int i = 0; i < resp->header_count; i++) {
    asprintf(&raw_resp, "%s%s", raw_resp, resp->headers[i]);
    bytes += strlen(resp->headers[i]);
  }

  if (resp->content != NULL) {
    asprintf(&raw_resp, "%s\r\n", raw_resp);
    raw_resp = realloc(raw_resp, bytes + 2 + resp->content->size);
    memcpy(&raw_resp[strlen(raw_resp)], resp->content->data,
           resp->content->size);
    bytes += (resp->content->size + 2);
  }
  write(socket, raw_resp, bytes);
  free(raw_resp);
}
```

Basically, it adds the HTTP request line first, then the headers and finally if needed the body.

However, valgrind is reporting a `Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()` and `18 bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 2 of 4` (memory leaks) on the first 2 asprintf but weirdly not on the 3rd one.

Am I using asprintf right?

Comment: Where do you `free` the memory allocated by the first two `asprintf` calls?

Comment: and the 'first' can be several because in a _for_ ... and its result is not used

Comment: Sidenote: you can avoid a lot of strlen()s if you use the return value from asprintf()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code does not `free` all the strings allocated by `asprintf`. Given how you use `asprintf` to perform dynamic string concatenation, fixing this problem is a bit cumbersome. Note that you do not handle memory allocation failure either. You could use `asprintf` return value to detect that and update `bytes` without the need for an extra `strlen()` call.

```
/* return the number of bytes written or -1 in case of error */
int write_response(request *req, response *resp, int socket) {
    char *raw_resp, *new_p;
    int bytes;

    bytes = asprintf(&raw_resp, "HTTP/1.1 %d %s\r\n", resp->code, resp->reason_phrase);
    if (bytes < 0)
        return -1;

    for (int i = 0; i < resp->header_count; i++) {
        bytes = asprintf(&new_p, "%s%s", raw_resp, resp->headers[i]);
        free(raw_resp);
        raw_resp = newp;
        if (bytes < 0)
            return -1;
    }

    if (resp->content != NULL) {
        bytes = asprintf(&new_p, "%s\r\n", raw_resp);
        free(raw_resp);
        raw_resp = newp;
        if (bytes < 0)
            return -1;
        new_p = realloc(raw_resp, bytes + resp->content->size);
        if (new_p == NULL) {
            free(raw_resp);
            return -1;
        }
        raw_resp = new_p;
        memcpy(raw_resp + bytes, resp->content->data, resp->content->size);
        bytes += resp->content->size;
    }
    bytes = write(socket, raw_resp, bytes);
    free(raw_resp);
    return bytes;
}
```

Remarks:

- Using `asprintf` to perform string concatenation with allocation seems inefficient, simply use `strlen`, `realloc` and `memcpy`.
- `asprintf()` is non-standard, it is not be available on all platforms.
- Unless you are requested to issue a single call to `write`, it might be more efficient to write the contents separately to avoid the extra call to `realloc()` for a potentially large amount of memory.
- It might also be more efficient to compute the length of the headers in a initial phase with `snprintf` and `strlen` and allocate the space for the headers directly to the full size, or not even allocate if below a reasonable threshold (4K) using a local array.

Here is a modified version:

```
int write_response(request *req, response *resp, int socket) {
    char buffer[4096];
    char *raw_resp, *allocated = NULL;
    int bytes, pos;

    bytes = snprintf(NULL, 0, "HTTP/1.1 %d %s\r\n", resp->code, resp->reason_phrase);
    for (int i = 0; i < resp->header_count; i++)
        bytes += strlen(resp->headers[i]);
    if (resp->content != NULL)
        bytes += 2 + resp->content->size;

    /* need an extra byte for `snprintf` null terminator 
       if no headers and no contents */
    if (bytes < sizeof(buffer)) {
        raw_resp = buffer;
    } else {
        raw_resp = allocated = malloc(bytes + 1): 
        if (raw_resp == NULL)
            return -1;
    }
    pos = snprintf(raw_resp, bytes, "HTTP/1.1 %d %s\r\n", resp->code, resp->reason_phrase);
    for (int i = 0; i < resp->header_count; i++) {
        int len = strlen(resp->headers[i]);
        memcpy(raw_resp + pos, resp->headers[i], len);
        pos += len;
    }

    if (resp->content != NULL) {
        raw_resp[pos++] = '\r';
        raw_resp[pos++] = '\n';
        memcpy(raw_resp + pos, resp->content->data, resp->content->size);
        pos += resp->content->size;
    }
    bytes = write(socket, raw_resp, bytes);
    free(allocated);
    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: In your modified version, you only perform 1 call to write. Also, how can you make sure `resp->content->data` is not going to overflow in buffer without realloc?

Comment: @Arkon: indeed I did not implement all suggestions. Regarding potential buffer overflow, `if (resp->content != NULL) bytes += 2 + resp->content->size;` at the end of the initial phase ensures enough space is allocated.

Answer (score 5):

This is what the man page says:

> The  functions asprintf() .... allocate a string...

and later

> This pointer should be passed to free(3) to release the allocated storage when it is no longer needed.

Every new call leads to a new allocation. You don't seem to free the previously allocated string .

Answer (score 1):

You have missing frees, and you do not need *asprintf* except the first time

Can be:

```
void write_response(request *req, response *resp, int socket) {
  char * buff;
  int len;

  len = asprintf(&buff, "HTTP/1.1 %d %s\r\n", resp->code, resp->reason_phrase);
  if (len == -1)
    .. error management

  for (int i = 0; i < resp->header_count; i++) {
    size_t hlen = strlen(resp->headers[i]);

    buff = realloc(buff, len + hlen + 1);
    if (buff == NULL)
      ... error management
    strcpy(buff + len, resp->headers[i]);
    len += hlen;
  }

  if (resp->content != NULL) {
    buff = realloc(buff, len + 2 + resp->content->size);
    if (buff == NULL)
      ... error management
    buff[len] = '\r';
    buff[len + 1] = '\n';
    memcpy(len + 2, resp->content->data, resp->content->size);
    len += resp->content->size + 2;
  }
  if (write(socket, buff, len) != len)
    ... error management
  free(buff);
}
```